# Ability to rollback changes when insert data using a server API

Tags: java, mysql, httprequest, server-application

I currently have the following situation:

I have build a client Java application, which used to communicate with the MySQL database directly. When I was inserting a lot of data, I used to do this with `AutoCommit` turned off. This was easy to do, because I had direct access to the `Connection`. I had chosen to do this, because it enabled me to rollback the changes when something went wrong during the synchronization.

Now, the application is evolving and I thought I would be better to build a server API which communicates with the MySQL database. So, at the moment, I am inserting data by doing Http requests. Each request opens and closes a new `Connection`.

Now, I would like to be able to rollback the changes when one of the requests goes wrong. I assume I can not work with `AutoCommit`, because this is based on a `Connection`, and that one is different for each request.

**Can anyone tell me how this is done usually?**

I have thought of the following:

- First call an URL which sets the `AutoCommit` to false, and then do all the requests and check if one fails. But this would go wrong if another client is also inserting data at the same time.
- Sending the data to the server with one request, but this would force me to alter my design drastically.

Note: I know some code is usually required when asking a question, but I can not see how this would improve my question. However, if it is needed, feel free to request it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every web request should run in it's own transaction.

Send all the data that belongs to a logical transaction in one request and call commit at the end of the request processing.

Spaning transactions accros multiple web requests is a bad idea. Think about crashing clients which never commit. This will leave you with open transactions that never close.